# Finding the area bounded by $r = a(1-\sin\theta)$ and $r = a$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Consider the cardioid $r = a(1-\sin\theta)$ and the circle $r = a$. We have that the cardioid meets the origin at an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, while it reaches its maximum distance from the origin at $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{2}$. The circle $r = a$ is simply a circle of radius $a$. I wish to find the area bounded by these two figures. I suppose their points of intersection would be quite helpful, so we set $a(1 - \sin\theta) = a \implies 1- \sin\theta=1 \implies \sin\theta = 0 \implies \theta = 0, \theta = \pi$.

So we have two points of intersection and an idea of how the figures look in the Cartesian coordinate-system. What is the logic here? To find the area of both figures and subtract one from the other, or is there a more standard method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: graph of functions]

Since you already have an idea what the functions look like, here's a pretty diagram.

Now obviously, our area is equal to

$$\frac\pi2a^2 + 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac12[a(1-\sin(\theta))]^2\,d\theta$$

Think you can take it from here?

Comment: I can solve the given integral, yes, but I still lack understanding of the intuition used. You have taken the area of half the circle, and of course, you are referring to the bottom half. Now, all that's left in the area is the small cardioid. I'd argue its $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}a^2(1-\sin\theta)^2$. Why have you put the extra theta there?

Comment: isn't there a extra theta?

Comment: @ketan typo yes.

Comment: @DavidMitra it should be $rd\theta$ no? I used symetry over the left and right halves to get the 2.

Comment: @AndrewThompson read above comment

Comment: But the formula for area in polar coordinates is $\int_\alpha^\beta (1/2) r^2\,d\theta$. See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArea.aspx).

Comment: @DavidMitra okay you're right. edited. okay now?

Comment: @DavidMitra okay.